# Looping through nested array of objects and limit values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js

I need solution for iterating through array and only get 5 items at once and on click a function get called display 20 more items.I need to iterate through array display only 5 items at once and on click add another 5 items to existing array and display it.Is there any way to complete it?

Suppose a object

```
let someObject = [
  {
    data: [
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    data: [
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    data: [
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here I render name

```
const Item = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.avatarText}>{item.name}</Text>
    </View>
)
```

I map through objects since it is nested I need to add items.data

```
someObject.map((items,indexes) => (
    <View key={indexes.toString()}>
      <FlatList 
        data={items.data}
        renderItem={Item}
      />
    </View>
))
```

Now like I need to display only 5 items of data at once and onclick add another 5 items of data to the list

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable for current index and increase it on click. For example:

```
const currentIndex = 0;
showButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  displayItems(someObject[currentIndex]); // your function for displaying items
  if (currentIndex !== someObject.length) {
   currentIndex++;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let someObject = [
  {
    data: [
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    data: [
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    data: [
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      },
      {
        id: 123,
        name: 'anything'
      }
    ]
  }
]
//map someObject into its item.data;
const lists = someObject.map(item=>item.data);
//im going to assume you start with the first five items being displayed
let index = 0;
let displayedOnScreen = lists[index];
let interval;

myClick();
//simulates click
function myClick(){
    index++;
    displayedOnScreen = displayedOnScreen.concat(lists[index]);
    console.log(displayedOnScreen);
  }
//if you want to display all items
   // console.log(lists.flat())
```